# Testacular with jasime does not show names of tests being run

Tags: jasmine, karma-runner

Using Testacular with Jasmine to run tests on Chrome.  I don't see any output other than "Executed 3 of 3 tests Succeeded".  How can I get testacular to show which tests are being run, and/or a progress bar?

```
// Testacular configuration
// Generated on Tue Mar 05 2013 11:12:54 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)

// base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
basePath = '';
port = 9876;
runnerPort = 9100;
singleRun = false;
autoWatch = true;
captureTimeout = 60000;

colors = true;
logLevel = LOG_ERROR;
loggers: [{type: 'console'}];
reporters:['progress'];

// Start these browsers, currently available:
// - Chrome
// - ChromeCanary
// - Firefox
// - Opera
// - Safari (only Mac)
// - PhantomJS
// - IE (only Windows)
browsers = ['Chrome'];

// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files = [
  JASMINE,
  JASMINE_ADAPTER,
    '../js/vendor/lodash.js',
    '../js/vendor/angular-1.0.2/angular.js',
    '../js/vendor/angular-1.0.2/angular-resource.js',
    '../js/vendor/angular-1.0.2/angular-mocks.js',
    '../js/vendor/angular-ui.js',
    '../js/vendor/angular-strap.js',

    '../js/objects/Route.js',
    '../js/config.js',
    '../js/objects.js',
    '../js/app.js',
    '../js/services.js',
    'unit/**/*.js'
];

// list of files to exclude
exclude = [];
```